# How to make a query to get column difference between two followed rows

Tags: django

I'm trying to get the difference between a row column and the next row column.
For example:

```
 pk | hour  | ts 
----+-------+----
  1 | 10:30 | 0
  2 | 10:50 | 20
  3 | 11:00 | 10
```

Where `ts` is the difference between `hour` column between *next* element and *current*

I don't want to get all objects and then do this using python because in production there will be a lot of rows and I heard it becomes inefficient.

So I've tried several ways.

**Option 1** - Using raw sql with `LAG`:

```
Computer.objects.raw('''
    SELECT id, hostname, date, date - LAG (date) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS lagged FROM hub_computer
''')
```

When accessing an element, it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1461, in __getitem__
    return list(self)[k]
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1421, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1408, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1431, in iterator
    query = iter(self.query)
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 109, in __iter__
    self._execute_query()
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 143, in _execute_query
    self.cursor.execute(self.sql, params)
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

**Option 2** - Using django window function `Lag()`:

```
Computer.objects.annotate(diff=F('date')-Lag('date'))
```

When running, it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: LAG

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 252, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 276, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1144, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rickerp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such function: LAG
```

I've search the entire internet, there is not much info about this, and about how to use django `Lag()` function

I would love if anyone could help me

Best regards,
rickerp

Comment: You need to use `Lag` in a `Window` function - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions

Comment: @IainShelvington hmm that did something....
Now, it gives this error O.o
`django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: This backend does not support window expressions.`   

The command runned: `Computer.objects.annotate(diff=Window(expression=Lag('date'), order_by=F('date').asc()))`

Comment: You're using sqlite? You'll need to use a different DB if you want to do this

Comment: Yes, i'm using sqlite for testing. Using sql (mariadb) in production.
I will change! Thank you!

Comment: Changed to mysql, still not working... Giving the same error @IainShelvington